# Numba compilation fails in parallel for loop

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to make use of prange in Numba to paralellize a routine that shifts arrays over an irregularly defined grid. In this example, the grid is just equidistant for simplicity.

Here's the code

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange


@jit( nopython=True, parallel=True )
def roll_arrays( a, shift_values,x_grid ):
       
    x_max          = np.amax(x_grid)       
    total_items    = a.shape[0]  
    the_ddtype     = a.dtype    
    result         = np.zeros( (a.shape[0], a.shape[1] ), dtype=the_ddtype )
           
    for k in prange( total_items ):        
        edge_val_left  = a[k,0]
        edge_val_right = a[k,-1]  
        #extend grid to edges with boundary values (flat extrapolation)
        extended_boundary = np.abs( shift_values[k] )#positive or negative depending on shift 
        
        if( shift_values[k] != 0.0 ):
                   
            x0_right          = np.linspace( x_max, x_max + extended_boundary, 10 )
            x0_left           = np.linspace( -x_max-extended_boundary, -x_max, 10 )
            if( shift_values[k]>0.0 ):
                #we fill left values
                x_dense_grid  = np.concatenate( ( x0_left, x_grid + shift_values[k] ) )
                x_dense_grid  = np.unique( x_dense_grid )                
                ynew          = np.concatenate(  ( edge_val_left*np.ones( 10 ), a[k,:] )  )            
                
            elif( shift_values[k]<0.0 ):
                x_dense_grid  = np.concatenate( ( x_grid + shift_values[k], x0_right ) )
                x_dense_grid  = np.unique( x_dense_grid )                
                ynew          = np.concatenate(  ( a[k,:], edge_val_right*np.ones( 10 ) )  ) 
            
            max_index     =   x_dense_grid.shape[0] - 1
            mid_x_index   =   np.int( x_dense_grid.shape[0]/2 )
            shift_index   = - ( np.argmin( np.abs( x_dense_grid - shift_values[k]) ) - mid_x_index )                  
                 
            if ( shift_index < 0 ):
                ynew[ max_index+shift_index: ] = edge_val_right*np.ones( np.int(1+ np.abs(shift_index)) )
            elif ( shift_index > 0 ):
                ynew[ 0:shift_index ] = edge_val_left*np.ones( np.int(np.abs(shift_index)) )
            if( shift_index ==0 ):
                print("I'm zero")   
           
            #return on the original grid                       
            f_interp    = np.interp( x_grid, x_dense_grid, ynew )                
            result[k,:] = f_interp  
        
        else:
            #no shift
            result[k,:] = a[k,:]             
    
    return result

x      = np.linspace(-10,10, 2001)
shifts = np.array([-1.0,-2.0,1.0])
f      = np.array( [ k/( x**2 + k**2 ) for k in range(1,shifts.shape[0])  ] )
fs     = roll_arrays( f, shifts, x)

print("done")
```

The problem is the use of "prange" in the k-th loop, as the error displayed i:

```
TypeError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: convert to parfors)
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

So I'm guessing the convert to parfors fails due to some race condition or equivalent; is there a way to overcome this issue in the above routine? The error does not occur if I drop the `"parallel=True"` decorator.

Comment: This really looks like a bug. I got a different error on my machine but with the same behaviour (using Numba 0.54.1). I simplified the code so to more easily locate the error. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Nyni6KhB) is the minimal code to reproduce the problem. Do you have the same issue with this one? I advise you to fill an issue on the Numba github (otherwise it will certainly not be solve any time soon).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will report this issue.